# Android & sqlite - Do I have to create and replace the database before accessing it? or can I just open the db and query?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, opendatabase

I am starting to learn android development using the Eclipse SDK with SQLite.

If I have an existing database, which I created manually, in another application etc.
It seems as if all the examples, even the ones which bring in an existing database, are forced call create a blank db first, then replace it with the existing db.

why can't I simply connect to it, and query from the existing data?

For example, using "openDataBase" or similar?
Does anyone have a very simple example of this... sample project with code?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that. Make sure DB path is pointing to correct DB. Then, you can just open and query the database.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  but how?

Comment: Thanks, this seems to take care of the problem.  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to package the database with your app then that is the only way.  If you load it separate from the app (web, USB, whatever) then yes, you can access it directly AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, planning to package a read only database with my app.   Question is, how to I simply access the database, select from the table and display the data? Eventually, with a prompt?